# java.net.BindException: Permission denied as root

Tags: java, exception, port

I'm following Oracle's ServerSide Socket tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html. I use the source as they provide it:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockServer.java
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockProtocol.java

However, when I try to run the KnockKnockServer, I get an IOException and then the server prints

```
Could not listen on port: 4444.
```

I added a `e.printStackTrace()` in the IOException catch block, and get:

```
[beni@mackerel:~]$ \sudo java KnockKnockServer
Creating socket
Could not listen on port: 4444.
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:106)
    at KnockKnockServer.main(KnockKnockServer.java:41)
```

Notice, I'm running it as root and try to open port 4444. Why do I still get a Permission denied error?

Comment: Port 4444 is already being used?

Comment: Port 4444 isn't a protected port, so you wouldn't *need* root access.  I'm thinking that the port is already in use.

Comment: What does the command `netstat -a | grep 4444` returns ?

Comment: Those are two separate commands being used in one :
(1) netstat -a will give you all ports and services
(2) grep is for searching for all things strings returned from the above commands with text "4444" which means you can get those that are using 4444.

Comment: No, the port is not in use. `netstat -a | grep 4444` returns nothing.

Comment: Just in case anyone runs into this issue with a port lower than 1024 on Mac OSX; the OS treats ports less than 1024 as privileged ports that only root can access. Try a higher port.

Comment: I had the same error when using port 79 on Ubuntu.  Grep returned no results.  When I changed the port to 11179, it binded without the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem. I had Hands Off! installed on my system, but disabled all rules from the menu bar. The KnockKnockServer still couldn't open the port. Now I have uninstalled Hands Off! completely, and can open ports as usual.

It is still a bit surprising, because I was always able to open the same socket port with `nc -l 4444` and with a C program, but not from Java. But at the same time, Hands Off didn't ask me if I want to allow my KnockKnockServer to open a port.

I will follow up with the Hands Off support, maybe they can help.

Thanks, Regards
Benedikt

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation that I can think of is that the bind is being denied by SELinux.

Comment: I run this on Mac OS X 10.7.4. I am not aware that there is SELinux here.

Answer (score 0):

4444 port is used by another program.

go to task manager and process tab check any javaw.exe is running. end the program.then run your program

Comment: No, the port is not in use. `netstat -a | grep 4444` returns nothing.

Comment: If the port was in use you would get a different exception message.